# WxPython: Segmentation fault in MAC

Tags: macos, wxpython

I have a application in which google map is integrated and which works perfectly fine in windows.

I am getting the below error in MAC:

wxWebKitCtrl::RunScript - Unexpected return type: __NSCFNumber!
make: *** [run] Segmentation fault: 11

wxPython: 2.8.11.0
MAC :  El Capitan 10.11.3
Python: 2.7.9

What can be the issue?

Comment: try again with 3.x or do bug report.